# Android xml layout (with picture)

Tags: android, xml, layout

I need some help with an Android Layout. 
What I want to achive is a Layout where the views around the grey view are growing with the screensize and the view in the middle is always centered. 
If the screen would be so small that in touches the grey views left and right should have the width of 0...
I have made an Imageviewer the grey area is the image and the outer areas all have a black background. the image should match the screen if the screen is small. but if it grows the image shall not scale, but the areas around it should grow...i hope you understand what i mean.
Maybe a vertical linear layout with a horizontal layout in it?

thank you!

[image: Example]

Comment: Are the outside views going to contain anything or just be a black border around the image?

Comment: they are not going to contain anything. just a black border around the image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

1. Use RelativeLayout
2. Use fixed size say 400dp x 400dp for the middle (grey) square
3. Use android:layout_centerInParent="true" for the grey square
4. Position top to be above and alignParentTop=true,
5. bottom to be below and alilgnParentBottom = true
6. left: toTheLeft of center and below top, above bottom
7. right: toTheRight of center, below top, above bottom

Here we go:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/center"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:background="#343434" />
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/top"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/center"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="#ababab" />
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/left"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/center"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/center"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/center"
        android:background="#cfcfcf" />
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/right"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/left"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/left"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/center"
        android:background="#cfcfcf" />
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/bottom"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/center"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="#ababab" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: If you don't want to place anything in top,left,right,bottom you can actually leave just your center widget (layout) and give black background to the parent RelativeLayout as described in @leenephi answer

Answer (score 0):

You can handle big and small screens by setting up dimensions for various screen dimensions, so for example:

values/dimens.xml:

```
<resources>
    <dimen name="margin"0dp</dimen>
</resources>
```

values-w480dp/dimens.xml:

```
<resources>
    <dimen name="margin"3dp</dimen>
</resources>
```

values-w600dp/dimens.xml:

```
<resources>
    <dimen name="margin"6dp</dimen>
</resources>
```

etc.

Now you can set your margin in your ImageView like this:

```
android:layout_marginRight/Left="@dimen/margin"
```

Don't forget to set your ImageView to

```
android:gravity="center"
```

If your layout just consists of only this ImageView then you can leave out the margin and just set the gravity to center.

Answer (score 0):

If all that outside space is just going to be a black background like you said, then why not just have one RelativeLayout with an ImageView centered inside it with a fixed layout_width and layout_height that will stay the same on all devices. Set the RelativeLayout with a black background. This way would perform better, and really, if all you want is a black border around the image, you don't need to worry about having actual layouts everywhere else. As long as you set a fixed width and height and center it, it should perform just as you want.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:src="@drawable/apache" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Like that. Or use "100px" if you want to be really specific I suppose.. though that's not recommended.